# why loop in function is not looping in python

Tags: function, loops, for-loop

In python I am trying to create a comma function
that take a parameter list
and add , and space at end of all elements in the and add "and " before last element no comma     after last element

```
def comma(listhere):
  if len(listhere) > 0:
    for x in listhere:
        listhere.insert(-1,"and ")
        liststring=""
        liststring += (str( listhere[x])+", ") 
        return print(liststring)

comma([0,1,2,3,4,5,6])
```

but I only get result

```
0,
```

no other results why this happens
Help

Comment: You have used 'return' within the loop, so it is returning after the first iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll tell you you're problems I encountered :

1. Don't return a print statement , return the list.
2. Declare the list outside of for loop. It keeps resetting to "" because you declared it inside of  for loop.
3. Return the list outside of for loop.
4. Use indexing to check if it's last element and then append accordingly, you're and.

Answer (score 1):

Ya I got the answer

answer is:

```
    def comma(listhere):
      if len(listhere) > 0:
       # listhere.insert(-1,"and ")
        liststring=""
        listlast=listhere[-1]
        del listhere[-1]
        for x in listhere:
          liststring += str(x)+", " 
          print(liststring)
        liststring += "and "+str(listlast)
      return liststring

    print(comma([0,1,2,3,4,5,6]))
```